# How to email UK border control to know whether I need a transit visa or not

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork

I have a flight from Beirut to London then Boston in two days and I will need to pass through immigration. I have an immigrant visa to the US, a connecting flight to Boston, and my mother and brother are US residents, so the EU travel ban doesn't apply to me. I'll get to London at 18:30 May 22, and I'll have to leave at 11:15 May 23. Who can I contact to know whether I need a transit visa or not? The airlines that is flying me from Beirut to London wants proof that I will be able to enter... Should I contact UK embassy or border control or whom? I can only contact border control by mail, not by phone.

Comment: This is a reframing comment. If you're confused about needing a transit visa — and from your three previous questions on the same subject I imagine you are confused — the conservative course of action is to obtain a transit visa to eliminate the possibility that you'll be refused for not having one. If you cannot obtain a transit visa in the few days before your flight, you must weigh (for yourself) the chance of refusal against the difficulty of changing your flight to a later time.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Welp, my flight is in two days. I know they probably can't help, but can contacting the UK embassy clear it out for me?

Comment: I've pointed you back at the page in gov.uk that you've already seen, and asked about here, and been told you don't need a transit visa. What more do you want from us?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to ask, but be prepared for no response or a "We don't give advice or issue UK visas, go to our online partner."

Comment: @dwarfhunter12 Are you moving to the US right now, or have you already been stamped in using the immigrant visa? If it's your first entry, do you have a sealed envelope from the US embassy?

Comment: @Crazydre Haven't been stamped yet. Don't think the US embassy gives sealed envelopes. 
Yeah I know :/ I'm just trying to know for sure whether I need it or not cause my mom is really anxious. This'll be my last post. Sorry.

Comment: @dwarfhunter12 What did you get from the embassy?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass In fact OP **does** need a visa, at least to board the flight, as the TIMATIC information is slightly different to that in the GOV.UK visa checker

Comment: What's your citizenship? What paperwork do you have? USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa? US Immigration Form 155A/155B? Something else?

Comment: I've got a Lebanese citizenship. The I-551 is only for those who have already entered the US. and I don't know what 155A/ 155B is and i can't find anything of that sort on the internet.

Comment: @jcaron OP's Lebanese and only has an unused immigrant visa, with no accompanying visa packet, and so will **not** be allowed on a flight to the UK

Comment: What is the "IV Category" of your visa?

Comment: @MichaelHampton F4

Comment: @MichaelHampton Has absolutely zero relevance, at least not in terms of boarding a flight.

Comment: @Crazydre It does when Timatic says it does.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Agreed, though I see no reference to that regarding transit in the UK. Could you quote it?

Comment: So, how did this end? Did you try boarding the flight? Did everything go smoothly? Did you encounter any issues?

Comment: @jcaron Hey dude, thanks for asking. Middle East Airlines offered me a refund and I took the opportunity. I'm very rude and sorry that I bothered y'all for quite some time and ended up not going. Sorry.  And apparently I wouldn't be allowed to stay in transit overnight as per MEA's rules for repatriation flights.

I booked and was guaranteed boarding on a chartered QatarAirways flight on June 5 from Beirut to Doha to Chicago on a single ticket with little layover time in Doha.  QatarAirways contacted RCLG and ensured that I am able to enter this way. So now I have some sort of peace of mind.

Answer (score 2):

Since the dissolution of the Border Force NICE unit, there's no Border Force unit that liaises with the general public.

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for [...] making a landside transit with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country that departs before 23:59 the next day. They must [...] have an immigrant visa issued by the USA with a US entry stamp

and

> Visa required, except for [...] making a
>   landside transit with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight
>   to a third country that departs before 23:59 the next day.
>   They must have a standalone immigration visa form 155A/155B issued by the USA together with a sealed brown envelope

In other words: if this is when you're moving to the US, present the sealed envelope at airline check-in and at the UK border. Otherwise, just show the immigrant visa in the passport (with the entry stamp next to it).

The check-in staff at the airport should go by TIMATIC, so refer them to it if necessary. They MUST put "USA" in the "Alien residency" field, or the exemption will not show.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108262/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-how-to-email-uk-border-control-to-know-whether).

Answer (score 1):

The UK rules, as show on the [official UK check if you need a visa website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/lebanon/transit/somewhere_else/yes) state that you can transit without a visa with a landside transit (going through immigration) on the next day if:

> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> One of the following must also apply:
>
> - you’re travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for
>     that country
> - (...)
> - you have a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998
> - you have a valid USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be accepted)
> - (...)
> - you have a valid standalone US Immigration Form 155A/155B issued by the USA (attached to a sealed brown envelope)

So if you had a US PR card, you can TVOW landside the next day to/from any destination. Without a PR card, you can do so as long as you hold a valid US visa AND travel to/from the US.

This is reflected in Timatic, which states that **if you are a US PR**, you can TWOV if you:

> - have an immigrant visa issued by the USA with:
> - a US entry stamp, and
> - the following statement printed above the machine readable zone of the visa: "Upon endorsement serves as temporary I-551 evidencing Permanent Residence for 1 year" (...)

Or if you:

> - have a standalone immigration visa form 155A/155B issued by the USA together with a sealed brown envelope (...)

Or if you:

> - have a Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998 (...)

If you are not yet a US PR (which you are not), then Timatic states that you must:

> - have a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand or USA, and
> - be traveling to the country that issued the visa, and

You may encounter a stubborn agent in Beirut that will consider you to already be a PR **and** only applies the rules for PRs, but the likelihood of this is IMHO quite low. There is no reason for UK authorities to refuse the transit (if of course all the usual conditions are met).

As you already have your ticket and it's non-refundable, I really think your best option is to go to the airport and board your flights. In the worst case, you will be denied boarding in Beirut, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, note that I'll be using two separate tickets. Will that change anything?

Comment: @dwarfhunter12 You need to bring the printed connecting boarding pass

Comment: The thing is: if holders of an unused immigrant visa aren't yet PRs, then neither are holders of the sealed envelope. It is to be opened at the US border specifically to activate the immigrant visa, i.e. the PR status.

Comment: @Crazydre Yo sorry to bother you again, but I was talking to my brother's housemate in the US and he wants the Terminal 2 Border Force Number to verify, if I could have it, thanks :)

Comment: @dwarfhunter12 The number is +44 20 8929 3824 (which I called) or +44 20 8929 3825. Ask them to look at their guidance, explain it's about landside transit, and that you have a valid US immigrant visa. Ask them to read out what the guidance says about it, because you've received conflicting information.